# Why is std::unique_ptr reset not the same as assignment?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, variable-assignment, unique-ptr

I am trying to understand why

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> p = new MyClass;
```

Does not work, but

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> p;
p.reset(new MyClass);
```

is fine. I somewhat understand how they are different, but I would like to know why the choice was made to make them different. What is the danger in assignment not being the same as reset?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>` is a different type than `MyClass`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Firstly, `std::unique_ptr<MyClass> p = new MyClass;` is not assignment, it is [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). And it doesn't work because the [constructor of `std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) taking a raw pointer is marked as `explicit`:

> ```
> explicit unique_ptr( pointer p ) noexcept;
> ```

It is declared as `explicit` to avoid unexpected (might be dangerous) **implicit** conversions, eg:

```
void foo(std::unique_ptr<int> uptr);

int *rptr = new int;
foo(rptr); // suppose rptr is implicitly converted to std::unique_ptr<int>
           // then the ownership is passed to the parameter uptr

// when foo() returns uptr is destroyed; the pointer managed by it is deleted too
// since rptr has been deleted continue to deference on it leads to UB
*rptr = 42; // UB
```

Note that `explicit` constructors are not considered in [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) (eg `std::unique_ptr<MyClass> p = new MyClass;`). You can use them in [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) instead (eg `std::unique_ptr<MyClass> p (new MyClass);`). They are used to prohibit implicit conversions, but you can perform explicit conversions. Like the usage of `reset`, you have to do these things **explicitly**, to show (and make yourself) that you're pretty sure about what you're doing.

BTW: The assignment from raw pointer doesn't work either, because `std::unique_ptr` doesn't have an overloaded assignment operator taking a raw pointer as parameter. For the reason above, raw pointer can't be **implicitly** converted to `std::unique_ptr`, so the move assignment operator (which takes `std::unique_ptr` as parameter) won't be considered either.

Comment: But 
```std::unique_ptr<MyClass> p;
p.reset (new MyClass);
p = new MyClass;```
Is assignment for sure? It is still not allowed. I can see how the function call, implicit constructor can be very dangerous.

Comment: So why not? If the constructor is explicit, why not have an operator = from raw pointer that just does a reset?

Comment: @starmole: Because it could happen *accidentally*. You are far more likely to accidentally assign a naked pointer to a `unique_ptr` than you are to accidentally type ".reset()".

Comment: @starmole If `std::unique_ptr` could be assigned from both raw pointer and `std::unique_ptr`, it's still possible to make careless mistakes. So you have to call `reset` explicitly, to show that you're pretty sure about what you're doing.

Comment: So, something I have to try out: In @songyuanyao example, even if the constructor was explicit, if there would be an operator =. that operator would still happen?

Comment: @starmole Sorry I can't get your question.. Where's the `operator=`? Which operator happens?

Comment: Note that in the case where you actually need to reassign the pointer, you can simply do `p = std::unique_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass);` or, even better, if you are already on C++14, `p = std::make_unique<MyClass>()`.

Comment: @starmole yes, if there was a `std::unique_ptr<T>::operator = (T *)` that would be called. But note that this would be not only risky but also useless: you shouldn't have raw owning pointers floating around anyway.

Comment: The idiomatic way to create unique pointer is `auto p = std::make_unique<MyClass>()`. It would be useful to say that in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

> I am trying to understand why
>   `std::unique_ptr<MyClass> p = new MyClass;`
>   does not work

The same reason as @songyuanyao mentioned, where it's declared `explicit`, tells that you can still initialize it in [a *different* form of initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) that surpasses `explicit`:

```
// Valid, since now it's 'explicit'
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> p { new MyClass{} };
```